# Identify number associated with each entity in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am not sure if this title is appropriate for the question, so let me explain in detail what is it that I am trying to achieve. This is not my actual project scenario I am using this as an example.

Consider a scenario where a user is trying to buy fruit's.

The user can say to bot:

1. I need 2 apples and an orange
2. I need 1 apple and 1 orange
3. I need an apple and 2 oranges
4. I need an apple and an orange

Suppose I have an entity `fruits` that identifies fruits and I am using `@sys.number` to identify the number of fruits.

In my current logic, I am taking the `entities` fruits and `@sys.number` as list and mapping each based on the index, ie first fruit in list will be mapped to 1st number in the other list, and if the number's list doesn't have a corresponding index for a fruit in fruits list, I'll assume it as 1.

This is just an adjustment and wont work for message type **3.** mentioned above.

Ideally I have to identify which number was mentioned against which fruit. Is there any way to do this ?

I will be able to do this by looking at the `queryText` in **fulfillment request** and parsing the text to see the order, but is there a way to make dialog flow itself to provide this information for us ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I've tried your scenario on my own.

I'm not sure whether it's the best practice or not but In this configuration, where I've separated every fruit and its number by a separate parameter. And by adding some appropriate training phrases, it's working as expected (As shown in the simulation window on the righ side).

[image]

It will also work fine if you say just `1 Apple` or `2 Oranges`.

In the earlier configuration, I've made single fruit and number parameter with list support but it gives problem, and in future, if fruits are increased then it's hard to maintain indexes. So I think it's better to have separate parameters for each fruit rather than having a list.

Comment: What happens in case of 'I need an apple and 2 oranges' ? Instead of '1 apple' ? It will give fruits1, fruits2 and number1 only right ? I still wont know weather it was for the 1st fruit or the second ? I am wrong ?

Comment: As shown in the screenshot I've tried the same sentence and it gives `number1 empty -> fruit1 Apple` (there's a fruit and the corresponding number is empty so you can assume it's one) and `number2 is 2 -> fruit2 is Orange`

Comment: Okay, that looks good I'll check it out and accept the answer after that. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: How to solve the same problem when number1 is required?